# Select Condition Query in Room Persistence

Tags: android, sqlite, persistence, android-room

I am facing issue when I write condition in Select Query.I am not getting desired output.
I am new in using Room Sqlite.

Here is query in interface:

```
@Dao
public interface Chip_deo {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM chip_db WHERE appChipsTemplateDetailID =:appChipsTemplateDetailID")
  List<Chip_db> findChipTemplateDetailID(String appChipsTemplateDetailID);
```

This is where I need to get:

```
Log.e(TAG, "chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): "+String.valueOf(chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID()) );
List<Chip_db> chip_dbs=chip_deo.findChipTemplateDetailID(String.valueOf(chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID()));
Log.e(TAG, "getChipsDataFromInput: "+ chip_dbs.size());
```

Output is:

```
04-20 15:04:24.612 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 4
04-20 15:04:24.614 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 1
04-20 15:04:24.615 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 7
04-20 15:04:24.617 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 6
04-20 15:04:24.618 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 5
04-20 15:04:24.619 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 3
04-20 15:04:24.621 14868-14868/com.xyz E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
chipDb.getAppChipsTemplateID(): 2
04-20 15:04:24.622 14868-14868/com.xyz  E/ChipsFragment: getChipsDataFromInput: 0
```

I just need the condition here **ListSize** is getting 0 always i.e query is not right so do help from this problem in room